# MongoDB on macOS 11.3.1 M1 connects on CLI but not Compass

Tags: node.js, mongodb, macos, apple-m1

I've recently purchased an M1-based MacBook Air and am trying to run MongoDB locally.

When I connect to the database using the CLI, it works just fine. However, if I try to connect using Compass using the `mongodb://127.0.0.1:21017/` connection string, I get `Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established` as an error.

Even trying to connect to it via a NodeJS application returns `MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017`.

I've been writing code with MongoDB for a while now, even on an intel-based Mac, but I'm not sure if the issue I'm having is due to the chip, some versioning mismatching, etc.

If anyone could help me debug this I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

just you need change localhost x 127.0.0.1:27017